# JavaScript clearInterval() does not clear the timer

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to set up a timer that will play a sound after a certain amount of minutes have passed. The number of minutes can be set in the input field `time`.

The problem is `clearInterval` function is not working.

When I set a timer to let's say 1 minute and afterward to 2 minutes, both timers are active.

How to remove the first-timer after changing the timer to 2 minutes only the new one will play a sound?

**HTML:**

```html
<input id="time" /> 
<button onclick="timeFunction()">
    set Timer
</button>

<p id ="timer"></p>
```

**JS:**

```js
function timeFunction() {

var minuten = document.getElementById("time").value;
var sec = minuten * 60;
var msec = sec * 1000;

document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Timer set to " + minuten + " minutes";

clearInterval(inter);

var inter = setInterval(function(){
   document.getElementById('gong').play(); }
    ,msec);

}
```

Comment: You are setting `inter` after clearing it...

Comment: Your variable is local to that function. When the function exits, that value is lost. The next time the function is called the value will be `undefined`.

Comment: Assuming you want the interval to occur more than once? Because otherwise you would use `setTimeout()`, wouldn't you.

Comment: Yes it should work like a loop timer!   @Pointy:  Thanks, declaring inter outside the function solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var inter` is a variable that only exists in your `timeFunction`. When the function finishes, `inter` does not exist anymore. When `clearInterval` runs, `inter` is undefined, because you haven't assigned it a value yet.

To fix it, declare the `inter` variable *outside* of your function. This will allow it to keep a value between multiple executions of `timeFunction`.

```
var inter;

function timeFunction() {
  // other code

  clearInterval(inter);

  inter = setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById('gong').play();
  }, msec);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you return the interval,

```
function timeFunction() {

var minuten = document.getElementById("time").value;
var sec = minuten * 60;
var msec = sec * 1000;

document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Timer set to " + minuten + " minutes";

return setInterval(function(){
   document.getElementById('gong').play(); }
    ,msec);

}
```

then you could go,

```
let intervals = timeFunction();
```

then you can clear it like so,

```
clearInterval(intervals);
```

this way you control how many times it iterates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to run only once clear the interval after your work has been done. So your function can be re-written like this:

```
function timeFunction() {
  var minuten = document.getElementById("time").value;
  var sec = minuten * 60;
  var msec = sec * 1000;
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Timer set to " + minuten + " minutes";
  var inter = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('gong').play();
    clearInterval(inter);
  }, msec);
}
```

**EDIT**

You can also return `inter` variable from your function so you can use `clearInterval` whenever your script's logic needs the interval to stop.

```
function timeFunction() {
  var minuten = document.getElementById("time").value;
  var sec = minuten * 60;
  var msec = sec * 1000;
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Timer set to " + minuten + " minutes";
  var inter = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('gong').play();
  }, msec);
  return inter;
}

let intv = timeFunction();

// rest of your javascript 
// ...

clearInterval(intv);
```

Comment: If the timer is going to be cleared inside the `setInterval()` callback, it will only run once. Why not use `setTimeout()` in that case?

Comment: @Pointy indeed this is going to run once and you can also use `setTimeout`.